# How to Center Align Text Widget and then add a leading icon to the text?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In a Row widget, I added a text Widget and I am able to center align the text by using `mainAxisAlignment.center` but when I add an icon before the text, the text obviously is now not centre-aligned because both Icon and Text get centre-aligned together.

Find below the screenshot for better understanding.

My designer suggested to have the **"Morning"** text centre-aligned to the *screen* and the icon should be prefixed to the text, how can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a transparent color trick:

```
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.wb_sunny, color: Colors.yellow),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Text('Morning'),
          ),
          Icon(Icons.wb_sunny, color: Colors.transparent),
        ],
      )
```

The right icon is needed only for balance, and has a transparent color.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the [wrap widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)?

As your column view is the horizontal center. Then it will adjust your view to center and you can also add the space between the image and text.

Comment: I haven't tried it for this case, but the time slots at the bottom are in a wrap and according to my understanding if I use it for this case it will be the same as row and the center will make it center for both elements in the wrap.